# how to display all categories in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I used this code:

```
      $categories = wp_get_post_categories(get_the_ID());
      foreach($categories as $category){
          echo '<div class="col-md-4"><a href="' . get_category_link($category) . '">' . get_cat_name($category) . '</a></div>';
        }
```

but return only one category, how can i get all the categories?

Comment: That is showing you the categories selected for the post you are on - do you want to show all the available categories on the site?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In the code you gave us you are selected the categories selected for the specific post get_the_ID() is doing that part. However you would be best off using another function get_categories() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/ which you would do like so:

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category) {
   echo '<div class="col-md-4"><a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></div>';
}
```

You can also pass through arguments to be more specific (if needed) - see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/ for details on what you can pass through

Comment: it's working good.. in this i want to get this category first post image in category so how can i get first post image with category..?

Comment: get_categories(); not return all categories. it will return only that category which has post. it will not return category which has count = 0. how can i get all categories including that who has no post?

Comment: @priyankapatel look at the link under the code example referring to arguments - you can add an argument to return all categories `'hide_empty' => false` is what you are after.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use wp_list_categories and pass arguments to it to show only what you need. A full list of arguments can be found in the codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories

This will output all categories (even if they're empty) indented to indicate hierarchy.

```
$args = array(
    'child_of'            => 0,
    'current_category'    => 0,
    'depth'               => 0,
    'echo'                => 1,
    'exclude'             => '',
    'exclude_tree'        => '',
    'feed'                => '',
    'feed_image'          => '',
    'feed_type'           => '',
    'hide_empty'          => 0,
    'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    'orderby'             => 'name',
    'separator'           => '<br />',
    'show_count'          => 0,
    'show_option_all'     => '',
    'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
    'style'               => 'list',
    'taxonomy'            => 'category',
    'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' ),
    'use_desc_for_title'  => 1,
);

var_dump( wp_list_categories($args) );
```

Answer (score 6):

like this :

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
) );

foreach( $categories as $category ) {
 echo '<div class="col-md-4"><a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></div>';   
}
```

Comment: ok tnx but why this code return 3 times the same category?  I have 4 different  categories whith at least one article.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wp_list_categories();
```

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not as native as it could be, but I always use:

```
$categories = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the_category();

Displays category list for a post in either HTML list or custom format.