# Display multiple category name wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Looking to display all category names for wordpress posts on a specific post.

So if a post is in "web design, seo and social media" i want these category names to display on the post - and NOT all the other categories such as "app design" which it is not related too.

```
<p>
    <?php $category = get_the_category();
    echo $category[0]->cat_name;
    echo " / ";
    echo $category[1]->cat_name;
    echo " / ";
    echo $category[2]->cat_name;
    ?>
</p>
```

this works currently but if there is only 1 category then i get extra / on the end of the displayed text.

Can someone else with a loop that works better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display all categories in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704715/how-to-display-all-categories-in-wordpress)

Comment: @rid no this displays ALL the categories and NOT the categories specially related to that post. so doesn't work as required.

Answer (score 1):

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$cat_id     = $categories[0]->term_id;

foreach ( $categories as $i => $category ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" >' . esc_html( $category->name ).'</a>';
    if ( $i < $count - 1 )
        echo $separator;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code show undefines the `$count` variable but when I use this code it shows some categories.

```
  <?php
                  $categories = get_the_category();
                  $cat_id     = $categories[0]->term_id;

                  foreach ( $categories as $i => $category ) {
                      echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" >' . esc_html( $category->name ).'</a>';
                      if ( $i < 'count - 1' )
                          echo $separator;
                  }

               ?>
```