# Display all category names for current post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Using this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000310/display-multiple-category-name-wordpress) as a guide, I've assigned multiple categories to my post (of a custom post-type). Trying to display all the assigned categories using this code, which is placed in a separate file entirely, `project-clipping.php`.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$cat_name   = $categories[0]->name;

foreach ( $categories as $i => $category ) {
  echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );
  if ( $i < $count - 1 )
      echo $separator;
}
```

It works fine for the first category, but thereafter spits out a `notice: Undefined variable: count in...`. This occurs thrice, twice, etc. depending on the number of categories assigned to the respective post.

I've tried solving this by placing it in the loop itself, rather than an external file. Does not work.

I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704715/how-to-display-all-categories-in-wordpress) but it returns all the categories of the post-type, not the post.

Thank you.

Comment: you didnt define $count variable anywhere else, first define, it seems the variable holds the count of total catergories

Comment: Also are you using custom taxonomy?

Comment: No, I'm not using custom taxonomy, but am a custom post-type.

Comment: How can I define the `$count` variable so that it holds the count of total categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define count and separator variable it seems, try like this, change separator variable as per your need.

```
$categories = get_the_category( get_the_ID() ) // if you are using custom taxonomy replace with get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'your-taxonomy'); 
$separator = '|'; // define separator variable 
$count = count($categories); // define count
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) { // check if not empty
    foreach ( $categories as $i=>$category ) {
      echo esc_html( $category->name );
      if ( $i < $count - 1 )
      echo $separator;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you; this almost works; just that the same category is printed repeatedly

Comment: Thank you; copy-pasting your code resolved the issue. Why it is, I'll analyze.