# How do I display all categories in WordPress on posts page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display all existing categories in WordPress. Not just the categories of one single post but all the categories that exist for the default post type. I know the functions `get_categories()` and `wp_list_categories()`, but they only display the categories of the first post in the loop when I'm on the posts page (basically the index.php). There must be a simple way to get around that but I just can't make it work. Feeling a bit stupid by now.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to display all categories in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704715/how-to-display-all-categories-in-wordpress)

Comment: Unfortunately not, the get_categories function only gives me the categories of the first post WordPress can find, not all existing categories

Comment: are you sure that all categories have at least one post associated to them? The `get_categories()` function ignores the blank categories, you need to pass the `hide_empty` as `false` like this `get_categories(['hide_empty' => false])` in order to list all of them.

Comment: Aaaah that was the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, so I posted an official answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your reported scenario is because by default `get_categories()` is not returning the "empty" categories - categories that are not referenced by at least one post.
To get all categories, regardless of whether they are empty or not you should pass `hide_empty` as `false`, here is an example:

```php
$categories = get_categories(['hide_empty' => false]);
```